# Is it ok to do printing/logging in global object constructor or it's an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, constructor, global-variables, iostream, undefined-behavior

```
#include<iostream>
struct A {
  A () {
    std::cout << "A::A()\n";
  }
};
A my_a;  // works fine and prints the above line

int main () {}
```

According to C++ standard, order of global object initialization residing in multiple files is unspecified.
i.e. Global objects which are defined in 1 file will invoke their constructor in top to bottom order. However, if there are multiple such files, then which file will be 1st to last, is implementation defined or unspecified.

Now, `std::cout` and `my_a` both are global objects. Which means above code is a UB, is it correct (i.e. initialization fiasco)?
Possibly, the compiler might be smart enough to first initialize `std` objects before moving to the other ones. Still for the sake of clarity, is there any full proof way to perform logging for global objects lying across multiple files?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler *is* smart enough (the code for initializing `std::cout` contains one of those nifty counters, in GCC at least), and since the iostream header comes before your global object, I have a feeling that this is fine. But it might not be condoned by the standard...

Comment: @KerrekSB, in general `<header.h>` coming before global object shouldn't matter, unless some special static initialization happens as mentioned in one of the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is ok and not an UB. Usage of streams declared in `iostream` is clearly defined by standard.

### 27.4 Standard iostream objects

> 2 **The objects are constructed and the associations are established at some time prior to or during the first
>   time an object of class `ios_base::Init` is constructed**, and in any case before the body of `main` begins execution.
>   293 The objects are not destroyed during program execution.294 **The results of including `<iostream>`
>   in a translation unit shall be as if `<iostream>` defined an instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage**
>   duration. Similarly, the entire program shall behave as if there were at least one instance of `ios_base::Init`
>   with static storage duration.

Thus standard requires that `cout` is initialized prior to first creation of `ios_base::Init` and `#include<iostream>` guarantees that it will be there. Thus by including iostream you implicitly define `ios_base::Init` static instance and guarantee that cout will be working correctly.

Also note 294 explicitly states that constructors and destructors of static objects are are allowed to use those objects.

> 294) Constructors and destructors for static objects can access these objects to read input from stdin or write output to stdout
>   or stderr.

C++03 Edit:
While all quotes previously given are per C++11 and C++03 doesn't have "define `ios_base::Init` on iostream include" rule. C++03 still have comment about constructors and destructors of static objects under #260 instead of 294, so for C++03 it is still allowed to use cout in static object constructor.

Comment: So it is UB if `ios_base::Init` doesn't yet exist?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore how it may not exists if it there is static instance required to be defined? See 2nd bold sentence.

Comment: Yup, wasn't there when I asked the question.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore bold part was the same, thru my comment wasn't clear enough indeed, fixed that.

Comment: Note that there is a restriction though; and the program as written is brittle. The problem is that you can perfectly define `A::A()` in one TU (including `<iostream>`) and define `A my_a;` in another (not including `<iostream>`, it compiles without!). In this latter case, unfortunately, you have initialization order fiasco. On the other hand, Luchian's (now deleted) solution works regardless of whether `<iostream>` is included in the TU defining the object.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Are you sure? Isn't there a rule that global initializers in a TU have to run before any functions in that TU run? Does that rule include member function definitions?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Even apart from Kerrek SB comment, there is note in standard that explicitly allows such usage. See my edit.

Comment: @alexrider: I believe that's new in C++11, isn't it ?

Comment: @KerrekSB: yes, but the trick here is that the global initializers of `std::cout` and `my_A` are placed in separate TU, and no guarantee is made across TU (in general), though it seems that at least C++11 places a specific guarantee for `std::cout` and co.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes but comment itself can be found in C++03 under 280) without any difference from 11th. While there is no definition of ios::Init upon iostream include given it is still allowed to use stream objects in constructor.